# How to display a determined item in a paging UIScrollView instead of just loading it from 0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uiimageview

I want to recreate the same concept that the iOS built-in gallery app does in a basic level, that means having an array of images and being able to look at them individually and swiping right or left to see the other ones in the array. For testing purpose, I've set a small array of UIImages, and then added an individual subview for every image that there is in the array to a scrollView with paging enabled. Everything works as expected, however every time I load the app, the user starts from the first item (item #0 in the array) and I don't find a way to select manually the first image that needs to be shown, for example what if I want the `scrollView` to first show the third image in the array, and then be able to swipe left or right to page to the other images in the array? I can't find a solution to it.

I've tried to add other subviews but this doesn't work, the app works as expected but always starts from the first item in the array, I want to manually select the item so if I want to display the third image in the array, the collectionView does it like so. I have six images for testing purposes (each called menu_icon_(0...5))

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView! {
    didSet {
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }
}

var images:[ImagePreviewView] = [ImagePreviewView]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    images = generateImages()
    setupSlideScrollView(imagesPreviews: images)
}

func generateImages() -> [ImagePreviewView]{
    var array:[ImagePreviewView] = []

    for i in 0...5 {
        let imagePreview = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ImagePreview", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ImagePreviewView
        imagePreview.userSelectedImageView.image = UIImage(named: "menu_icon_\(i)")
        array.append(imagePreview)
    }
    return array
}

func setupSlideScrollView(imagesPreviews : [ImagePreviewView]) {
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(imagesPreviews.count), height: view.frame.height)
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

    for i in 0 ..< imagesPreviews.count {
        imagesPreviews[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        scrollView.addSubview(imagesPreviews[i])
    }
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
    print("Page Index is \(pageIndex)")
}
```

I want to implement this code in such a way that the user adds images to a collection view, and when the user taps in an image, that `indexPath.item` is sent to this `viewController` and shows the image that the user selected, not the first image in the array, and then is able to swipe right or left. I'm trying to recreate how it would be only by the latter view controller logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you will receive the index when this VC is created. Lets call it `selectedIndex`

```
var selectedIndex = 0 //I give 0 as initial value but it will be updated anyways.
```

Then in `viewDidAppear` try with following:

```
let width = view.frame.width
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: width * selectedIndex, y: 0), animated: false)
```

So when a user taps to an image you will receive the index number of that image in your VC, then `setContentOffset` of scrollView to width of the screen times selectedIndex, this should give you the result you want.